# Zero object in array crashes the program, also after certain count

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios6, instagram

I have a program that grabs data from Instagram, puts it into dictionary and then I parse it.

Problems begin when I try to use that data, magically item number 0 crashes my program.

Also, after certain number next item also crashes the program.

Here is the code for UITableViewCell, that grabs text from the array/dictionaries and puts it into cell. As it looks, it crashes, if I add another check to start with number 1, it works, but crashes later when it reaches some count.
I don't understand why this happens, since I have the method that tells the TableView how many rows are in table, and it returns [self.loader.dataArray count], so it can't possibly try to load the thing that is out of bounds.

```
if (self.loader.dataArray[indexPath.row] != nil )
    {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.loader.dataArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"caption"] objectForKey:@"from"] objectForKey:@"full_name"];
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting:

instagramClient[8254:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3bb8f090'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception that you're getting does not indicate an out of bounds issue, it indicates that you have got an `NSNull` in your `dataArray` (or possibly in the "caption" object of one of the dictionaries in your `dataArray` or in the "from" object of one of those dictionaries, and so on).  Try logging all of `self.loader.dataArray` when you get updates to that array and see if it contains any `NSNull` objects.

Comment: Good catch, Aaron. I spoke too soon!

Comment: This worked, I logged all of it and inspected, and in fact I had wrong place to look for name - it looked for first commenter name, and if there were no comments it crashed.

Comment: Now it's time to mention that `!= nil` can be converted to `![... isEqual:[NSNull null]]`